# Why is the relation anti-symmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

This is a task from my exercise sheet in discrete math that lacks a hindsight.

Put A={1,2,3} and form the relation R on A by putting R={(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)}.

Investigate if R is antisymmetric.

My attempt:

Anti-symmetry means xRy ^ yRx => x=y. Since we don't have (2,1) (3,2) or (1,3) (which would mean x!=y) in R, but we find (1,1) and (2,2) in R, we draw the conclusion that xRy and yRx only when x=y, which is the condition for anti-symmetry? Would be happy if someone can explain this in a different way. Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xRy$ and $yRx \implies x=y$ means that if $x\ne y$ we never have both $xRy$ and $yRx$.

So check each pair:

$\{1,2\}$:  We have $(1,2)$ so $1R2$ but not $(2,1)$ so $1\not R2$ so we don't have both.

$\{1,3\}$: We have $(3,1)$ so $3R1$ but not $(1,3)$ so $1\not R3$ so we don't have both.

$\{2,3\}$: We have $(2,3)$ so $2R3$ but not $(2,3)$ so $3\not R2$ so we don't have both.

So it is anti-symmetric.

Finding cases where $xRx$ aren't relevant.  If $x=y$  then $xRy$ and $yRx$ are just two ways of saying $xRx$ and if you have $\color{blue}xR\color{red}x$ of course you also have $\color{red}xR\color{blue}x$ because they are the same statement and can't help being "trivially self-symmetric" and are not considered to be an issue to $R$ being symmetric or anti-symmetric.

Another way one can define antisymmetric could be:

Definition 2:  For any pair $x\ne y$ it is never the case that both $xRy$ ad $yRx$ is true.

Or Definition 3: For any pair $x\ne y$ then:  Whenever we have $xRy$ we do *not* have $yR x$.

Also note: you don't need *either* $x Ry$ nor $yRx$.  You can have one, or the other, or *neither*; you just **can't** have both.

So if $Q= \{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$ then $Q$ is (vacuously) anti-symmetric as well.

Comment: nice, exactly what I thought (+1)

Comment: Good explaination, but on line 3 u write "{1,2} : We have (1,2) so 2R1 but not not (2,1) so 1R̸2 so we don't have both." Is this "not not" a nestled not or just a writing error? Just so I don't get confused

Comment: Typo:  I originally refered to the three pairs as $(a,b)$ with the understand they are *not* ordered and I wrote "we have $aRb$ but not $bRa$, but then I realized that as $R$ was written as *ordered* pairs this would be dangerously confusing and an abuse and I rewrote the pairs as $\{a,b\}$ and add not just that we had/didn't have $aRb$ we has $(a,b)$ (or not).  In the cutting and pasting and highlighting and deleting.... two consecutive nots got in.

Comment: Just one final question, why is finding cases where xRx irrelevant?

Comment: Because having or not having cases where xRx won't mean a case is anti-symmetric. And having or not having cases where xRx won't mean a case is not anti-symmetric.

Comment: Its time for my presentation of this task soon and I've seen that you've probably written something wrong. U say that in (1,2) 2R1 but 1 doesnt not relate to 2. Then for the next ones you say (3,1) 3R1 but 1 does not relate to 3. You have said it in the wrong order in one of them and I need to know which one is wrong.

Comment: Don't trust what a bozo on the internet writes.  What does your *text* say.  I imagine $1 R 2$ means $(1,2) \in R$ because the opposite order is just too convoluted to make sense to me.  But check your text.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $(xRy \ \wedge \ yRx) \to (x=y)$ can be restated as
$$(xRy \ \wedge \ x\neq y) \to \neg(yRx)$$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: Which rule or law did you use to rewrite the statement like that?

Answer (score 0):

There is $(1,2)$, but not the symmetric $(2,1)$. You check this for all pairs.

Obviously, antisymmetry is no relevant for a pair like $(1,1)$.

A symmetric relation could be

$$R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)\}.
$$

And a relation neither symmetric nor antisymmetric:

$$R=\{(1,1),(2,2),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3)\}.
$$

Comment: can we say the relation is antisymmetric? since there does not exist any condition such that $xRy$ and $yRx$ but $x≠y$, so in my opinion the relation is trivially antisymmetric

Comment: I don't understand. I check for every pair that has different elements inside it if it has a reverse (there is (1,2) but not (2,1))? If there isnt a reverse for every pair with different elements inside it, the relation is anti-symmetric?

Comment: @JeanDoe: my second example answers this. Antisymmetric does not mean non-symmetric.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. What exactly makes this relation anti-symmetric?

Comment: @JeanDoe: symmetric = all pairs have their symmetric; antisymmetric = no pair has its symmetric. All vs. none.

Comment: Is that really correct though? I mean antisymmetry definition is xRy ^ yRx => x = y, you just say they are not symmetric since they dont have their reverse pair, therefore they are anti-symmetric. I don't think that is really correct

Comment: "so in my opinion the relation is trivially antisymmetric" what's "trivial" about it? I think a "trivially antisymmetric" relationship would be a relation on a set with one element ($x\ne y$ never happens) of an empty relation where there are no related pairs at as (so $xRy$ never happens). And a relation with only $(x,x)$ pairs would be *vacuously* antisymmetric (because there aren't any $xRy; x\ne y$).  But this relation is antisymmetric in the perfectly normal way: whenever there is an $xRy;x\ne y$ there *isn't*  $y Rx$.

Comment: Just to be thorough: A relation can be:1)neither anti-symmetric nor symmetric: If you have both $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ for one pair but for another pair you have $(c,d)$ but not $(d,c)$. 2) ***both*** anti-symmetric and symmetric! If you *only* have reflexive$(a,a)$ pairs and *never* have an $(b,c)$ pair when $b\ne c$. 3)symmetric but not anti-symmetric: if *every* time you have an $(a,b)$ you also have $(b,a)$ (and you have at least one $(a,b);a\ne b$). 4)anti-symmetric by not symmetric: if every time you have an $(a,b);a\ne b$ you *dont* have $(b,a)$ (and you have at least one $(a,b);a\ne b$).

Comment: @JeanDoe: grrr, I said that antisymmetry is not relevant for pairs like $(1,1)$.